# How can we integrate Skype API?

Tags: skype

Can we integrate Skype API in a website so that users can talk to the admins of the website using Skype? Do users need Skype username for that? Is there any site which has such functionality already?

Answer (score 3):

You can put a [Skype button](http://www.skype.com/intl/en-gb/share/buttons/) on your website that is linked to your admin's Skype account. When a user clicks on that button (and has Skype installed on their machine) it will automatically call your admin.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the [callto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme) scheme (do a search for `callto`) or the [skype](http://www.skype.com/share/buttons/advanced.html) scheme

Answer (score 2):

Skype4COM.dll should be able to do the job assuming you're in MS-land. You could create a number of Skype users yourself and manage the logins via the API.

EDIT: the DLL requires Skype installed, which is probably unlikely. In general, Jabber is easier for these thing because of that. Another problem with Skype is windows management, especially in a web page.  Consider [my SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627517/controlling-skype-via-its-skype4com-dll-com-api) on window management.

Answer (score 0):

Skype API is there for you to integrate in websites:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986863(v=office.16).aspx

Comment: This applies to Skype for Business (formally know as Lync). I assume the question is asking about the consumer Skype